# ignore a specific document in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello I want a user to update his profile data(username & email) but while doing I want to make sure he is Updating to a unique name ,so for that Ihave the following code

```
        mongoUser.find({username:usernme},(err,user)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        if(user.length>0){
            errors.push({msg:'This Username is taken !!!Try Another Username'})
        res.render('account',{
            errors,
            username,
            email,
            user:req.user
        })
```

})

but this query checks all the documents in mongodb which always return results,I want to ignore the document where the logged in user(the current user) data is.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is the $nin operator ,use `{username:{$nin:['loggedinusername']}}`,it will find docs which have username not in that aaray